# How do I sanitize data from users before sending it to mySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, security, sanitization

I am making a forum at this moment.

I would like to sanitize my input data (that is, the posts from users) before sending it to the MySQL database.

I already have been searching some functions to do that, but I'm not sure if I have used enough of them and if they're all secure enough. Any suggestions are welcome.

Here is the code I have:

```
$message=$_POST['answer'];
$message=nl2br($message); //adds breaks to my text
$message=stripslashes($message); //removes backslahes (needed for links and images)
$message=strip_tags($message, '<p><a><b><i><strong><em><code><sub><sup><img>'); //people can only use tags inside 2nd param
$message = mysql_real_escape_string($message); //removes mysql statements i think (not sure)
```

**edit:** Please tell me if I should add some tags to the strip_tags function. Maybe I have forgotten some.

Comment: [When inserting in db](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) and when [displaying the data on a page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php).

Comment: Still allows XSS in attributes like `<img onerror="…">`

Comment: Since your comment says you're not sure what `mysql_real_escape_string()` does, you should [read its documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) and while you're at it, [read about SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection) to understand why this is so important.

Comment: @jannesbraet just read the links I posted

Comment: nl2br() is for helping control output to a HTML block. stripslashes() is basically of no real value, it helps ''undo'' (bad) output escaping that  may have previously been applied (most useful for strings in a Javascript block). strip_tags() is a poor man's way of attempting to avoid cross-site scripting, that is only valid in one particular HTML output-context. None of these 3 functions things have anything to do with databases and will only serve to corrupt your data.

Answer (score 2):

Try using PDO instead. It has great binding function, which really improves security. Here's some examples: http://php.net/manual/pl/pdostatement.bindvalue.php

PDO is by default in PHP5, so pretty much everywhere these days.

Comment: If you write your own app use php5.3+.

Comment: i'm using a host server but it's from a dad from my friend so i can't contact them

Comment: Like NomikOS said, you should really switch to PHP5 (switch host?), especially with your security concerns.

Comment: is mysql_real_escape_string() so unsafe then? i was just wondering

Comment: Not "that" unsafe, but PDO or MySQLi is more reliable for sure.

Comment: If you have PHP 4.4.9 you may have much bigger problems. It has many security vulnerabilities and no longer receives any upstream security updates. Check that your distribution is still supported and you are receiving and applying regular patches from the OS-provider. If not, you really need to upgrade your OS

Answer (score 1):

If you want to allow limited HTML to be used in forum (as seen by the way you are using strip_tags()), use [HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/); otherwise you are vulnerable to javascript in attributes of those tags.

By the way, right now you are stripping the `<br>` tags you've added

Answer (score -1):

When you save to DB:

```
$message=strip_tags($message, '<p><a><b><i><strong><em><code><sub><sup><img>'); //people can only use tags inside 2nd param
$message = mysql_real_escape_string($message); //removes mysql statements i think (not sure)
```

When you output:

```
$message=nl2br($message); //adds breaks to my text
$message=stripslashes($message); //removes backslahes (needed for links and images)
```

Besides, use [htmlspecialchars](http://codeigniter.com/) when you write into html input elements like `text` or `textarea`

OBS: Don't reinvent the wheel. Learn some PHP framework like [codeigniter](http://codeigniter.com/) that provides very secure ways to manage data.
.